# SQL Server Join Multiple Tables with Aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having some issues writing a query to get the following:

Table 1 (zip to district): District, Region, Territory, zip code
Table 2: MemberID, Zip Code
Table 3: MemberID, Email Address
Table 4 (email sends): SendID, Count sends (unique email addresses)
Table 5 (email opens): SendID, Count opens (unique email addresses)
Table 6 (email clicks): SendID, Count clicks (unique email addresses)

Essentially I would like the following output:
District, Region, Territory, SENDID, Count Sends, Count Opens, Count Clicks

Thanks for your help!

EDIT to include query:

```
SELECT T1.TERRITORY, T1.DISTRICT, T1.REGION, 
       T4.SENDID, T4.SENDS, T5.BOUNCES, 
       T6.OPENS, T7.CLICKS
FROM ZIP_TO_TERRITORY AS T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT UZIPCODE,  ID FROM member_UNIVERSE) AS T2 ON T1.ZIPCODE = T2.UZIPCODE
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, EMAIL FROM client_EMAILS) AS T3 ON T2. [ID] = T3.ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT "SENDS" = count(distinct EMAILADDRESS), EMAILADDRESS, SENDID FROM ET_SENT GROUP BY EMAILADDRESS, SENDID) AS T4 ON T3.EMAIL = T4.EMAILADDRESS
INNER JOIN (SELECT "BOUNCES" = count(distinct EMAILADDRESS),EVENTTYPE,SENDID from ET_BOUNCES GROUP BY EVENTTYPE,SENDID) T5 on T4.SENDID = T5.SENDID
INNER Join (Select "OPENS" = count(distinct EMAILADDRESS),EVENTTYPE,SENDID FROM ET_OPENS GROUP BY EVENTTYPE,SENDID) T6 on T5.SENDID = T6.SENDID
INNER Join (SELECT "CLICKS" = count(distinct EMAILADDRESS),EVENTTYPE,SENDID FROM ET_CLICKS GROUP BY EVENTTYPE,SENDID) T7 on T5.SENDID = T7.SENDID
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to include the SQL that you have so far. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I just updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I came up with based on the code you have included.

```
SELECT T1.TERRITORY, T1.DISTRICT, T1.REGION, 
       T4.SENDID, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT T4.EMAILADDRESS) AS SENDS, 
       ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT T5.EMAILADDRESS),0) AS BOUNCES, 
       ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT T6.EMAILADDRESS),0) AS OPENS, 
       ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT T7.EMAILADDRESS),0) AS CLICKS
FROM ZIP_TO_TERRITORY AS T1
INNER JOIN member_UNIVERSE AS T2 
    ON T1.ZIPCODE = T2.UZIPCODE
INNER JOIN client_EMAILS AS T3 
    ON T2. [ID] = T3.ID
INNER JOIN ET_SENT AS T4 -- change this to a LEFT JOIN if you want to see categories that have no (0) ET_SENT records
    ON T3.EMAIL = T4.EMAILADDRESS
LEFT JOIN ET_BOUNCES T5 
    ON T4.SENDID = T5.SENDID
LEFT JOIN ET_OPENS T6 
    ON T5.SENDID = T6.SENDID
LEFT JOIN ET_CLICKS T7 
    ON T5.SENDID = T7.SENDID
GROUP BY T1.TERRITORY, T1.DISTRICT, T1.REGION, 
       T4.SENDID;
```

This replaces your nested queries with direct joins, albeit `LEFT JOINS` where it seemed appropriate. This is pretty standard stuff when it comes to aggregating data.

Assuming that `SENDID` is the ID for a message delivery attempt, this will roll up the attempt with its associated geography base categories, and give you counts for sends, bounces, opens and clicks.

This uses `COUNT DISTINCT` because that is what you have in your code. That may not be desirable. If not, remove the `DISTINCT`s from the code. Leaving the `DISTINCT` in the code may give you numbers that are lower than you want, or if there is a one-to-one relationship between a `SENDID` and an email, the `COUNT DISTINCT` will always be 1. I would remove them, but I will leave that to you. You can mix `COUNT` and `COUNT DISTINCT`, that is okay.

On the other hand, if the `SENDID` is really a campaign (mass mailing) identifier, then the `COUNT DISTINCT` may be exactly what you need. `:)`

As noted in the comment in the code, change that one `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` if you want to see categories (territories, regions, and districts) with zero sent events.

I didn't make any attempts to mock up any data for this, but the code compiled and ran with the mock tables I created based on your code.

Good Luck!